# Apache VirtualHost - Specific Env Vars

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, environment-variables, passenger

Successfully using `SetEnv` with virtualhosts on Apache2

Wondering if there's a way to set `virtualhost` specific env vars, or whether setting them at Apache-level makes them "global" / system-wide?

We have several apps we want to use one one box, and want to set ENV vars for each. Although we have this working with setting them in Apache's `conf` files, I was wondering if there's a way to securely declare them for local virtualhost scoping?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `SetEnv` in `<VirtualHost>` directive for it to be virtualhost specific.

You can also define it globally in your apache configuration.